# how to check if item is None in python scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

If `item['business_name']` is equal to this `[]` or `None`. I want to delete it from query results.

Instead it outputs this which is what i don't want, i only want query results that have a business name

> `'business_name': [],`

this is what i have so far

```
class Item(scrapy.Item):
    business_name = scrapy.Field()
    website = scrapy.Field()
    phone_number = scrapy.Field()

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    def parse(self, response):
        for business in response.css('div.info'):
            item = Item()
            item['business_name'] = business.css('span[itemprop="name"]::text').extract()
            if item['business_name'] is None :
                break
            else:
                item['website']  = business.css('div.links  a::attr(href)').extract_first()
                item['phone_number'] = business.css('div.phones.phone.primary::text').extract()
                yield item
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try:

```
if item['business_name'] is None or len(item['business_name']) == 0:
    # delete it here
```

Or turn your logic the other way round:

```
if item['business_name']:
    item['website']  = business.css('div.links  a::attr(href)').extract_first()
    item['phone_number'] = business.css('div.phones.phone.primary::text').extract()
    yield item
```

The latter makes use of `None` and an empty list being "falsy" in `Python` and is considered the more "Pythonic" way.

Comment: can you better explain why your way worked and mines didn't a more simple explanation :) thanks jan

Comment: also is there a way to check to see if there is any duplicates, like if business_name already exists delete from query, know what i mean ?

Comment: They have a duplicates filter, see https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

Answer (score 1):

A pythonic solution would be

```
if not item['business_name']: 
    Do something
```

Because both None and an empty list have boolean value of `false`